# Ef core tracking behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following two code snippets which do a similar thing

```cs
var camera = await dbContext.VideoCameras
            .Include(c => c.Users)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == request.CameraId, cancellationToken);

if (camera is null)
{
    return Results.NotFound("Camera was not found");
}
var users = await dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => request.UserIds.Contains(u.Id))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
camera.Users.Clear();
camera.Users.AddRange(users);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken)
```

```cs
var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_options.Value.BasePath).ToList();
var cameras = await _dbContext.VideoCameras.ToListAsync(context.CancellationToken);
var numberOfVideosAdded = 0; 
foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    var directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(directory).Name;
    if (cameras.All(c => c.Name != directoryName))
    {
        var newCamera = new VideoCamera()
        {
            Name = directoryName
        };
        _dbContext.VideoCameras.Add(newCamera);
        cameras.Add(newCamera);
// SaveChangesAsync is called later down
```

Why is it, that I explicitly need to call `_dbContext.VideoCameras.Add`? I don't understand why in the first example the `List` is tracked by EntitiyFramework and in the second it is not.

Further explanation: The two snippets don't try to do the same logic, they do something completely different. I want to understand why the tracking does not work in the second example if I remove the line `_dbContext.VideoCameras.Add(newCamera);` and only add to the `cameras` list as in both cases ef loads a list (`camera.Users` is a list and `_dbContext.VideoCameras.ToListAsync` is obviously also a list).

Can someone explain?

Comment: The list is never tracked by EF Core, only the *objects* loaded by EF itself. Those objects happen to be stored into a List in this case. You don't need to call `Add` for entities loaded by EF Core itself. `camera.Users.AddRange(users)` does nothing at all. `newCamera` is a completely new and unrelated object though. There's no reason for EF to do anything with it

Comment: The two snippets don't do the same thing at all. The first removes the relation between a Camera and users (eg by `UPDATE USER SET CameraID=null`) while the second inserts new cameras

Comment: I deleted my answer because not only the snippets show two completely unrelated things, the comment asks something unrelated too. The first snippet does replace a camera's users with others. What is the second one supposed to do and why are *new* camera instances created? What do directories have to do with the question?

Comment: It's unclear what folders have to do with the question. If we have a list of camera IDs and user IDs to assign as eg a `Dictionary<int,List<int>>`, we can load the cameras at once, load the required users per camera, replace the users and save all. No folders are involved. We can accelerate this by loading *all* the selected users in memory too, then match them to cameras.

Comment: I clarified the question. The snippets don't try the same thing. I just want to know why the tracking of ef core does not work if I only add a new entity to the loaded `cameras` list in the example

Comment: Tracking works just fine. I explained that tracking tracks the objects, not the containers they're put in

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your first comment makes sense as in the first snippet the list I add to is in an object tracked by EF. Post it as answer i'll gladly accept that, thank you

Comment: Not really. `Camera.Users` is just a List<>. It's not tracked by EF, Camera and User are. `List.AddRange` just adds items to that list. When you try to save changes EF will see that Camera.Users has different contents and so generate SQL to remove old relations and add new ones. You could have written `camera.Users=users;` and got the same behavior